# What are skipped tests in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I tried to run Visual Studio tests in ASP.NET MVC by pressing "Run All" but all tests were skipped. Why did this happen and how can I run all tests? Here is a screenshot:

[image: Skipped Tests]

Comment: Do you have a test settings file?

Comment: Yes, i have TestSettings.testsettings file.

Comment: Is the test settings file specifying which tests to run?  Mainly, under Folders, is the folder where your tests are located included?

Comment: Where can i find it, can you show screenshot?

Comment: try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx#VSTestSettingsUnitTest)

Comment: The screenshot doesn't look like Visual Studio's default test runner. What IDE/Test runner is this?

Comment: I have installed Resharper, but it have his own "Unit test Sessions" window.

Comment: Thank you kevin_fitz. I didn't read everything you said but just your questioning about whether he has a test settings file led me to solve my own issue. My tests were skipping because I had accidentally left 'remote execution' on in my test settings files which was fine before but now and I was intending on local execution.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but have you managed to solve this? I've run into the same issue, and i can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Are these tests written using MSTest framework? Or do they use NUnit. xUnit.NET or other frameworks. If yes would you install the corresponding test runner plugin?

Comment: @andyroschy did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds weird but I get this problem on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015, but it works fine with the exact same project copy/pasted over to Windows 7 with the same version of Visual Studio

Comment: After a reboot (of the whole computer, not just Visual Studio) the problem seemed to go away for me.

Answer (score 34):

Check if the test has a [Ignore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ignoreattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Running SpecFlow tests with Ignore attribute will make Test Explorer skipping the tests

Comment: I just would like to add a note to pay attention that Ignore attribute can either be applied in methods and classes.

Answer (score 8):

Tests which use the `Inconclusive` result will appear as skipped. So `VS 2010 inconclusive == VS 2012 skipped`

ex:

```
Assert.Inconclusive("This test didn't exactly fail, but we can't be certain the results are good.")
```

Will read as skipped in the test window

Answer (score 5):

The Test Settings file you're pointing to could be invalid.  Make sure the settings file has the right parameters (either remote or local, etc.), and then go to `Tests>Test Settings>Select Test Settings File` in the toolbar to select the valid file.

Answer (score 4):

I got this in VS 2015, along with QTAgent32 stopped working etc. Turned out to be nothing to do with test settings and was in fact a stack overflow *(I kid you not)* in the class I was testing.

I had several tests failing, and a whole swathe of others skipped when the agent went down. I commented out all the tests in the impacted area, until run all worked, then pulled them back in until a fail, then to see the actual SO exception I had to debug the test.

Then I face palmed a few times and fixed it.
Unlikely scenario, but you never know.

Comment: I've had similar issues when an Exception is thrown from the ClassInitialize, class constructor, or even default initialized attributes.... Not the case this time as I am hitting this issue with an empty class.

Comment: Maybe its skipped it Because its empty. There seems to be plethora of reasons why this happens, Personally I think Test32 neds an upgrade. I have a project where I can't debug tests. All seems a bit flaky.

Answer (score 3):

Also caused by testing a 64-bit project but test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture=x86

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that one of your tests beforehand didn't fail, your tests may have been skipped due to insufficient privileges.

You can use the "TestCategories" annotation on your tests. Mark them with:

```
[TestCategory("Admin") TestMethod()]
public Void Test1()
{
   ...
}
```

And then exclude the category:

mstest /testcontainer:MyTestprojectName.dll /category:"!Admin"

You can use multiple categories on each test.
For in-depth info: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's been mentioned here, check that the TestClass does not also have the Ignore attribute (not just the test method.)  This bit me once...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue and there's no accepted answer, but maybe this will help someone.

In Test Explorer (Tests -> Windows -> Test Explorer), you can see all the tests that were skipped. If you double-click on test name, it will open the actual Test code. Check if the test has an [Ignore] attribute and remove it if you want to run the test. (as @Sridarshan suggested)

P.S. I had NUnit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I had a setup script defined in my TestSettings.testsettings file that did not exist on my development machine.

```
<Scripts setupScript="C:\Deployment\UnitTestSetup.cmd" />
```

Comment: This was the problem for me, and it didn't give me any message about it.  It just skipped the test until I removed the script from the testrunconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

In xUnit, tests marked with `FactAttribute` for which `Skip` property is set to something are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be relevant for this exact case, but if none of your NUnit tests are running in the test explorer and they are being skipped, you might want to check if you have Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk nuget installed. It is needed.

[image]